# Tools to manage semantic webs

Tags: editor, semantic-web

I've seen a lot frameworks to create a semantic web (or rather the model below it). What tools are there to create a small semantic web or repository on the desktop, for example for personal information management.

Please include information how easy these are to use for a casual user, (in contrast to someone who has worked in this area for years). So I'd like to hear which tools can create a repository without a lot of types and where you can type the nodes later, as you learn about your problem domain.

Answer (score 1):

For personal semantic information management on the desktop there is NEPOMUK. There are two versions, one embedded in kde4, this lets you tag, rate and comment things such as files, folders, pictures, mp3s, etc. on the desktop across all applications. 
Another version is written in Java and is OS independent, this is more of a research prototype. It has more features, but is overall less stable.

For KDE-Nepomuk see http://nepomuk.kde.org/
For Java-Nepomuk see http://dev.nepomuk.semanticdesktop.org/ and http://dev.nepomuk.semanticdesktop.org/download/ for downloads (the DFKI version is better)

Answer (score 0):

Extensive list of [semantic web tools](http://esw.w3.org/topic/SemanticWebTools)

Also check out [Protege](http://protege.stanford.edu/overview/po-screenshots.html)

Comment: I had a look at Protege but that seems to be the opposite of what I'm looking for: First, you have to define the model and then you can fill it with data. How good is Protege with mostly unstructured data?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create a small model, then I suggest that you use [topbraid](http://www.topquadrant.com/products/TB_Composer.html). I have used for creating much larger models and I know people who have used to create humongous models. It comes packaged with a set of reasoners and provides ability to plug-in custom reasoner and in case if you decide to make your model larger, you can even integrate Topbraid with a triple store like Allegrograph.

And since its based on eclipse, to get started with it is relatively easier.

For developers who are spoiled working in more matured programming languages like Java (IDEA ? anyone), topbraid is the closest tool to an actual IDE.

Answer (score -1):

[Chandler](http://chandlerproject.org/) is a "a notebook you can organize, back up and share!" It seems to be pretty simple to use.

OS: Windows, Mac, Linux

Comment: Speculation: Chandler doesn't *seem* to be semantic web related, in the sense its not an RDF tool